# Create a Dictionary of a Property as a Key and List of Objects as Values from a List of Objects

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have a User Object  as follows

```
public class UserInfo 
{
    public string DepartmentCd { get; set; }
    public string DepartmentNm { get; set; }
}
```

And I have a list of `UserInfo` objects  and want to create a dictionary with `DepartmentCd` as key and `List<UserInfo>` Object as value (users who belong to that Dept)
Below code does it for me, but curious if there is a better and elegant way to achieve this.

```
var deptUserDict = employeeInfoList.GroupBy(x => x.DepartmentCd).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.ToList());
```

Comment: If you had not answered your question, I would write the same code, what more elegant code you are looking for? shorter? faster? more readable?

Comment: Just for my learning purposes checking if there is more efficient way to do this...somehow I feel there should be a better way than using group by...I may be wrong...doesn't know until we ask..having a working code !=efficient one..

Comment: Is the DepartmentCD unique for each UserInfo?

Comment: Seems like you would be duplication data. You have the DepartmentCD as the key for the dictionary and then the same DepartmentCD in the UserInfo List.